# Flutter: There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: A

Tags: flutter, dropdown

First of all, I try to google first but still not find the solution. Also, I try many options that I found on SO from googling but still not working. So, I open the question.

My code:

```
class AddRiderScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AddRiderScreenState createState() => _AddRiderScreenState();
}

class _AddRiderScreenState extends State<AddRiderScreen> {
  String _riderNameSelected = '';

  final List _listRiderName = [
    'Personal Accident (Risk A)',
    'Personal Accident (Risk B)',
    'Personal Accident (Risk C)'
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Title'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
        child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
          child: DropdownButton(
            hint: Text('-- Pilih --'),
            isExpanded: true,
            value: _riderNameSelected,
            items: _listRiderName.map((value) {
              return DropdownMenuItem(
                child: Text(value),
                value: value,
              );
            }).toList(),
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.arrow_drop_down,
              color: Colors.grey,
            ),
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                _riderNameSelected = value;
              });
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The Error:

```
There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: A. 
Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value
'package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart':
Failed assertion: line 834 pos 15: 'items == null || items.isEmpty || value == null ||
              items.where((DropdownMenuItem<T> item) {
                return item.value == value;
              }).length == 1'
```

Can someone know this problem and found the solution to how to fix this? Because I don't know how to fix this problem.

Comment: try `String _riderNameSelected = 'Personal Accident (Risk A)';` for example

Comment: Still not work, u can try it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter: There should be exactly one item with \[DropdownButton\]'s value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60510150/flutter-there-should-be-exactly-one-item-with-dropdownbuttons-value)

Comment: Please refer the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60510150/flutter-there-should-be-exactly-one-item-with-dropdownbuttons-value?rq=1

Comment: @pskink No, because I already add `hint` on the `DropdownButton` widget. So when this class is rendered, the `DropdownButton` button will show `-- Pilih --` first, not the value from `_listRiderName` array.

Comment: @BalasubramaniSundaram I already try that solution, but still getting the same error. You can try it then you will know what I get from that error.

Comment: @pskink I found the problem, it's because I add `''` in the `_riderNameSelected` variable. So I just remove that and the default value `-- Pilih --` is shown

Comment: this is what i said in my first comment here, you need for example: `String _riderNameSelected = 'Personal Accident (Risk A)';` (or just `null`) - not `String _riderNameSelected = ';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove `''` in your `_riderNameSelected`.

```
String _riderNameSelected;
```