# Why my drop down widget occurs an error when include value

Tags: flutter, dart

Currently I'm trying to implement dropdown using `DropdownButton`, but there is one problem.
In `DropdownButton()`, if `value:` is empty, error is not occurred but nothing change when choose.
if I assign an arbitrary String variable to `value:`, the following error will occur.

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown building StatefulBuilder(dirty, state: _StatefulBuilderState#65c7c):
Assertion failed:
..\…\material\dropdown.dart:915
items == null || items.isEmpty || value == null ||
              items.where((DropdownMenuItem<T> item) {
                return item.value == value;
              }).length == 1
"There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: . \nEither zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value"
```

---

My code;

```
List<String> strings = <String>["Aa", "Bb", "Cc"];
String selectedString = "";

@override
Widget build(BuildContext c) {  ....
showDialog( builder: (context) { 
    return Dialog(builder: (context, setState) {
        return SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(   ....

DropdownButton<String>(
                                   value: selectedString,    // IF THIS IS NOT NULL, THE ERROR NOT APPEARD
                                    hint: Text("Choose"),
                                    items: strings.map((String value) {
                                      return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                        value: value,
                                        child: Text(value),
                                      );
                                    }).toList(),
                                    onChanged: (value) {
                                      setState(() {
                                        selectedString = value!;
                                      });
                                    },
                                  ),
                                 ........
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was easy to solve.

[Flutter: There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60510150/flutter-there-should-be-exactly-one-item-with-dropdownbuttons-value)

This answer says that `selectedString` value should be string that exists in `strings`. Like this
selectedString = "Aa";

Answer (score 1):

You have to follow these three steps;

```
1. List<String> strings = <String>[" ","Aa", "Bb", "Cc"];

2. String selectedString = " ";

3. value: selectedString ,
```

Comment: I edit code  `value: selectedString` but this occurs same error.

Answer (score 1):

You must have at least one value that is contained in the list of items

1. List strings = [" ","Aa", "Bb", "Cc"];
2. String selectedString = " "; or "Aa" or "Bb" <******** !!
3. value: selectedString ,