# How to use DropdownButton without setting an initial select in flutter?

Tags: flutter

Hi I'm new to Flutter.

I had been getting an exception `There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: .` when using `DropdownButton` class. And it was resolved once by setting an initial select referring to this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60510150/flutter-there-should-be-exactly-one-item-with-dropdownbuttons-value).

But I don't want to set an initial value. Is there any way not to set it but no exception?

Thanks,

P.S.
I have two classes and one constant to show the dropdown button. Here is the constant that is a list for creating DropdownMenuItems:

```
List<String> prefectures = const [
  '北海道',
  '青森県',
  '岩手県',
  '宮城県',
  '秋田県',
  '山形県',
  '福島県',
  '茨城県',
  '栃木県',
  '群馬県',
...
```

And this is the class that expand `DropdownButton`.

```
class MyDropdownButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final String                 value;
  final void Function(String?) onChanged;
  final List<String>           options;
  final String?                hintText;
  const MyDropdownButton(
    {required this.value, required this.onChanged, required this.options, this.hintText, super.key}
  );

  List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> createOptions() {
    return options.toSet().map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>(
      (option) => DropdownMenuItem(value : option, child : Text(option))
    ).toList();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
      child : DropdownButton(
        elevation : 3,
        items     : createOptions(),
        onChanged : onChanged,
        style     : const TextStyle(
          color    : Colors.black,
          fontSize : 15
     　 ),
        value     : value
      )
    );
  }
}
```

And this is where I use the class above:

```
MyDropdownButton(
  // They are also passed from other class.
  value     : widget.prefectureValue,     // this has null value
  onChanged : widget.onChangedPrefecture, // (String? newValue) => setState(() => _prefectureValue = newValue);
  options   : prefectures
)
```

Comment: can you sample with dummy data that will reproduce the same error

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I edited my question so that you can see my code. Please check them.

Comment: ca you try commenting `value     : value`

Comment: I tried so, but I got an empty value in box.

Comment: seems there are no duplicate items now, can you provide the dataType on dropDownButton as I did and for initial value use null or `prefectures.first`

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I did all you told me, but it throws a new exception: `The following assertion was thrown building MyDropdownButton(dirty, dependencies: [MediaQuery]):
There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: .
Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value
'package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart':
Failed assertion: line 892 pos 15: 'items == null || items.isEmpty || value == null ||
              items.where((DropdownMenuItem<T> item) {
                return item.value == value;
              }).length == 1'`

Comment: your `MyDropdownButton` doesn't accept null `value`

Comment: I edited the post and then changed it to accept null value, but the exception one comment before was thrown.

Comment: try to follow the example code i've included

Comment: I did exactly same you told me, and it works! I really appreciate your detailed information. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value:* means you are having same value more than one DropdownMenuItem. You can convert the data-list to Set, most time it works.

Here the items is

```
 List<String> items = [...];
 String? selectedItem;
```

And the dropDownButton

```dart
DropdownButton<String?>(
  items: items
      .toSet()
      .map(
        (e) => DropdownMenuItem<String?>(
          value: e,
          child: Text(e),
        ),
      )
      .toList(),
  onChanged: (value) {},
)
```

Fixed model

```dart
class MyDropdownButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final String? value;
  final void Function(String?) onChanged;
  final List<String> options;
  final String? hintText;
  const MyDropdownButton(
      {required this.value,
      required this.onChanged,
      required this.options,
      this.hintText,
      super.key});

  List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> createOptions() {
    return options
        .toSet()
        .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>(
            (option) => DropdownMenuItem(value: option, child: Text(option)))
        .toList();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
        child: DropdownButton(
            elevation: 3,
            items: createOptions(),
            onChanged: onChanged,
            style: const TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
              fontSize: 15,
            ),
            value: value));
  }
}
```

Here is how I am using it

```dart
List<String> prefectures = const [
    '北海道',
    '青森県',
    '岩手県',
    '宮城県',
    '秋田県',
    '山形県',
    '福島県',
    '茨城県',
    '栃木県',
    '群馬県',
  ];

  late String? value = prefectures.first;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          MyDropdownButton(
            value: value, //null,
            onChanged: (v) {
              setState(() {
                value = v;
              });
            }, 
            options: prefectures,
          ),
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But it seems it doesn't work. As I edited my post to describe more in detail, I'd be glad you to check.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple keep the initialValue null provided that you are on the latest version of flutter 3.5 or above

```
var _selectedItem;
  Widget buildDropdownButton() {
    return DropdownButton(
      hint: const Text('Select Item'),
      value: _selectedItem,
      onChanged: (value) {
        setState(() {
          _selectedItem = value;
        });
      },
      items: ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4"]
          .map((e) => DropdownMenuItem(
                value: e,
                child: Text(e),
              ))
          .toList(),
    );
  }
```

the output will look like the following
[image]

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer. I tried to upgrade my flutter sdk version, but it still says the same thing: `There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: .` if I set a null value.